# Socket.IO is not triggering the connect event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to setup a Socket.IO server, and right now, connecting doesn't seem to be working the way it does in the Wiki. I'm connecting to a server using the namespace `/client`, and I'm successfully seeing the connection made in the debug log, but the connection message is never display (and the other contents are never getting attached).

### Server-side

```
var clients = io
    .of('/client')
    .on('connect', function (socket) {
        // This is never getting run
        console.log('Client connected');
    });
```

### Client side

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8082/client');
```

Why, in the above code, am I not getting the 'Client connected' message in my console?

Comment: @askovpen This is for node.js, so JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, turns out this is a very simple issue, as I suspected. The client uses the `connect` event, but [the server uses `connection`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events).

The code should look like:

```
var clients = io
    .of('/client')
    .on('connection', function (socket) {
        // This is never getting run
        console.log('Client connected');
    });
```